# foreach loop running twice?

Tags: powershell, foreach

Running this code in a script (that grabs details from a form) to get a list of users groups and remove from all except group named "Group1" and "Group2":

```
#remove any group memberships except Group1 and Group2
$groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Inputsamaccountname.Text | Where-Object -filter {$_.name -ne 'Group1' -And $_.name -ne 'Group2'} 
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $group = $groups.Name 
    $RemovegroupMsg = "Removing " + $inputSamAccountName.Text + " from " + $group
    logentryDateTime $removeGroupMsg
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $inputSamAccountName.Text -MemberOf $group -Confirm:$false
    if ($Error) {
        $errorMessage = "Error removing " + $inputSamAccountName.Text + " from " + $group + " " + ($Error[0].ToString()) + " continuing."
        logentryDateTime $errorMessage
        $Error.Clear()
        continue
    } elseif (!$Error) {
        Write-Output "" >> $outlogfile 
        logentryDateTime "Successfully removed " + $inputSamAccountName.Text + " from " + $group
    }
}
```

The script works and you can see that the groups have been removed, however logs show a "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null." error for each group that matches that criteria":

```
[2016-10-19 113117-820] : Removing user.test1 from Other-group
[2016-10-19 113117-820] : Error removing user.test1 from Other-group Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null. continuing.
```

I know it's likely something really simple in the logic of the `foreach` loop I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line seems like your problem:   `$group = $groups.name`  It is surprising to see you accessing the array (`$groups`) inside a foreach loop iterating across those elements.   Did you mean `$group = $group.name`?